# How to break into WinDBG when ntdll.dll is mapped into the new process

Tags: debugging, windbg

I want to use the following command to break into WinDBG when ntdll.dll is mapped into the new process, and before any of ntdll's process initialization runs.

**sxe ld ntdll.dll ;g**

However, the trick doesn't work at all,

```
ModLoad: 7c900000 7c9b0000   ntdll.dll
eax=010043af ebx=7ffde000 ecx=020f18f5 edx=00000034 esi=00c2f720 edi=00c2f6f2
eip=7c810867 esp=0006fffc ebp=00000720 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0038  gs=0000             efl=00000200
7c810867  ??              ???
Processing initial command 'sxe ld ntdll.dll ;g'
0:000> sxe ld ntdll.dll ;g
(ae8.6f4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00181eb4 ebx=7ffde000 ecx=00000001 edx=00000002 esi=00181f48 edi=00181eb4
eip=7c901230 esp=0006fb20 ebp=0006fc94 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c901230 cc              int     3
```

So, How to break into WinDBG when ntdll.dll is mapped into the new process?
thanks

**[UPDATE]**

I exactly followed the steps as mentioned by jcopenha, but I don't know why Windbg gives a strange error(**Memory access error**) where Notepad.exe is running  .

Please give me a hand!Thanks a lot!

```
0:000> .restart /f
CommandLine: C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE
Symbol search path is: D:\Symbols\Symbols;SRV*D:\Symbols\MySymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 01000000 01014000   notepad.exe
eax=0100739d ebx=7ffd9000 ecx=020f18f5 edx=0000004e esi=00f7f73a edi=00f7f6f2
eip=7c810867 esp=0007fffc ebp=0000024c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0038  gs=0000             efl=00000200
7c810867 ??              ???
0:000> u 7c810867
7c810867 ??              ???
            ^ Memory access error in 'u 7c810867'
```

**[UPDATE2]**
I found an odd instruction displayed at 7c810867, but p command still can work.

Is it a bug in WinDBG?

[image]

Comment: Hope someone can give me a hand! Thanks

Comment: The reason why the question marks appear is that you're using a kernel debugger, and the page tables are not present in that moment. So when you execute p (step over) the exception is handled by the Memory Manager and maps the memory to be available (thats why you see it).

Answer (score 5):

If you go to Debug->Event Filters and change "Create process" to "enabled" then restart the application it will start before ntdll.dll shows up in the module list.  If you then do `sxe ld ntdll.dll;g` it will stop in `ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart`.

```
0:000> .restart /f
CommandLine: C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
Symbol search path is: SRV*d:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00000000`ffe00000 00000000`ffe35000   notepad.exe
00000000`7790c500 4883ec48        sub     rsp,48h
0:000> sxe ld ntdll.dll;g
ModLoad: 00000000`778e0000 00000000`77a89000   ntdll.dll
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart:
00000000`7790c500 4883ec48        sub     rsp,48h
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the loading of ntdll, I recommend reading [this](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=205).  You can break into the process before any code runs with:

```
windbg -xe cpr notepad
```

Or

```
windbg -xe ld:ntdll notepad
```

ntdll will still be mapped into the process at this point -- you can't break in before this happens.

As for the memory access error, kernel32 is not loaded into the process yet.  The initial thread is queued to run at kernel32!BaseProcessStartThunk, but since kernel32 isn't loaded into the address space yet, you aren't going to see anything at that address.

The reason the thread's start address is able to begin in unmapped memory is because before the thread begins its execution, the very first thing that happens is a user APC runs in the context of that initial thread that takes care of all the process initialization, including loading kernel32.  You can see this event occur if you set a similar event, like:

```
sxe ld kernel32
```

You will need to load symbols to get the internal functions names in the stack trace.

In addition to the first link, you can read more about process initialization [here](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=127).  Hope this helps.

Comment: I also want to add that just because ntdll doesn't show up in the module list doesn't mean it isn't already mapped into the process.  Since ntdll has the same base address in every process in the system, you can get the base address of ntdll from any other process and display the memory at that address in your debugged process.  You will still see ntdll.  The reason it isn't showing up in the loaded modules list is because the module lists haven't been constructed yet in the PEB.  This also happens as part of the initialization.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember ntdll is not mapped by the user-mode. If it was mapped in by the user-mode, what would map the module that maps ntdll? ntdll contains a set of stubs for syscalls to enter into the kernel and also contains a few other things such as a COFF loader which is part of process initialisation. It is a bit of a magic dll and it cannot be relocated, thus is always at the same virtual address in every process.

If you want to break before ntdll is mapped I am afraid you will have to use a kernel debugger.

May I ask what you are trying to achieve by breaking before ntdll is mapped?